# Issue in IE8 : Jscript debugger. Breaking on JScript runtime error : permission denied

Tags: javascript, gwt, ie8-compatibility-mode, ie-developer-tools

I can't open gwt-html page in IE8 on my machine(loads in Mozila FF).
When I debug Js in my html page then I got following error message
**Jscript debugger.
Breaking on JScript runtime error : permission denied.** 
and JS not loaded on  that page.

But I can access same gwt-html page on other machine's IE8.

I re-installed IE8 on my machine still same problem occurs.

I got error message when i debug following line in javascript

**document.getElementById("hiddenID").value = window.opener.parent.document.getElementById("hiddenID").value;**

Is there any setting to resolve this issue ?

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help greatly if you posted the offending code.

Comment: @circusbred Thanks for reply. added code where error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be accessing a parent frame from an iframe? If you're getting permission denied issues with jscript runtime it may be a trusted site/cross domain scripting issue, are both domains added to your trusted sites?

Sometimes in IE8 the document.domain isn't set fast enough, I've had to call iframe functions after a timeout before to get it to work - or I get the same issues.